# python ctypes foreign library initialization and uninitialization

Tags: python, c, linux, ctypes

I am wrapping this c library called pvcam (Photometrics Virtual Camera Access Method) in ctypes and for the most part it works. The problem is I cannot get the library to uninit. When ever I try to uninit it says it was never inited.
Following are the code snippets in question.

```
libraw1394 = CDLL('libraw1394.so', mode=RTLD_GLOBAL)
libpvcam = CDLL('libpvcam.so', mode=RTLD_GLOBAL)
```

after loading the libraries, I've setup the `pvcam_init()` function

```
pl_pvcam_init = libpvcam.pl_pvcam_init
pl_pvcam_init.argtypes = []
pl_pvcam_init.restype = ctypes.c_int
def pvcam_init():
    pl_pvcam_init()
    if not pl_error_code():
        return
    else:
        print('pl_pvcam_init() failed : '+error_message(error_code()))
```

and the `pvcam_uninit()` function

```
pl_pvcam_uninit = libpvcam.pl_pvcam_uninit
pl_pvcam_uninit.restype = c_int
pl_pvcam_uninit.argtypes = []
def pvcam_uninit():
    pl_pvcam_uninit()
    if not pl_error_code():
        return
    else:
        print('pl_pvcam_uninit() failed : '+error_message(error_code()))
```

these `error_code()` and `error_message(error_code)` functions are simple and they seem to work fine, Just in case you need to look at them

```
pl_error_code = libpvcam.pl_error_code
pl_error_code.argtypes = []
pl_error_code.restype = c_int
def error_code():
    error_code = pl_error_code()
    return error_code
```

and

```
pl_error_message = libpvcam.pl_error_message
pl_error_message.restype = c_int
pl_error_message.argtypes = [c_int16,c_char_p]
def error_message(error_code):
    char_msg = '                         ' #large string to hold error description
    pl_error_message(error_code, char_msg)
    return char_msg
```

a simple `pvcam_init()` followed by `pvcam_uninit()` returns

```
pl_pvcam_uninit() failed : C0_PVCAM_NOT_INITED       Camera library not initialized
```

i.e. the `error_code()` and `error_message(error_code)` are working :),
Also if i do a `pvcam_init()` followed by `pvcam_init()` again

```
pl_pvcam_init() failed : C2_PVCAM_ALREADY_INITED     Init_pvcam has been called twice without closing
```

If I just move on to opening up the hardware and acquisition etc., after `pvcam_init()` everything works until the point I want to close the program. Why doesn't the `pvcam_uninit()` see the prior `pvcam_init()`?

the pvcam api doc is here [PVCAM 2.7 Software User Manual.pdf](ftp://ftp.piacton.com/Public/Manuals/Princeton%20Instruments/PVCAM%202.7%20Software%20User%20Manual.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

According to the API doc, `pl_pvcam_init()` returns "TRUE for success, FALSE for a failure. Failure sets
`pl_error_code`".

I don't know much about this library, but it is probable that `pl_error_code` is unset/invalid if the call to `pl_pvcam_init()` succeeds. So you should probably check for its return value before calling `error_code()` and `error_message()`.

Comment: That plus `error_message` should use a writable buffer `char_msg = (ctypes.c_char * MSGSIZE)()` and then return `char_msg.value`. Don't modify a Python string.

Comment: I changed it to check the return value of pl_pvcam_uninit() and it seems to return that it executed fine so I've modified the functions to check what the function call returns and then to check error_code only if it returns a fail. It seems to be working now. Will test it further, Thanks
@eryksun may I please know why I shouldn't modify the Python string? Because I always thought if I specify an argtype as c_char_p I can just pass a Python string and let it be altered, just made sure the string size (i.e. MSGSIZE) is large enough for what ever is going to come out.

Comment: @user3371330, basically a Python string is immutable, and when you violate this contract you're now deep in implementation details that you shouldn't have to worry about as a Python programmer. That's why the docs tell you to use `create_string_buffer` instead. That's a convenience function for creating a `c_char` array from an initializer string. I usually just create the array directly, as I showed above.